# How to have a tab containing flexible height menu fixed at bottom of window and slide up on click using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I tried coding it myself based on research on the internet.  I was able to get it fixed at the bottom.  When clicking, it does slide out the menu; but it slides out downwards when it should have pushed the tab upwards to display the menu.  If I use negative margin and simply change `bottom: -150` to `bottom: 0px` on click, it does produce the desired behavior by sliding it up from past the bottom of the window and it displays correctly.  But it means the menu is pushing the page past the bottom of the page rather than simply being hidden. So when it's "hidden", one can simply scroll down and see the full menu which shouldn't be the case.

So rather than using `bottom` to manipulate it, I tried using `$(this).show("slide")`. The menu came out looking distorted thanks to using the sliding animation.

Here's the snippet:

```js
var supTabState = false;
$("#dccontainer").css('bottom', '-150px');
$("#dcsupporttab").click(function() {
  $('#dcsupportcontainer').slideToggle(500, function() {
    //execute this after slideToggle is done
  });
  supTabState = !supTabState;
  if (supTabState) {
    //    $("#dccontainer").css('bottom', '0px');
    $(this).show("slide", {
      direction: "down"
    }, 1000);
  } else {
    //    $("#dccontainer").css('bottom', '-150px');
    $(this).show("slide", {
      direction: "up"
    }, 1000);
  }
});
```

```css
#dccontainer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 300px;
  left: 50%;
  height: 200px;
  margin-left: -150px;
  transition: .5s;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#dccontainer * {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  font-family: 'Roboto', 'Helvetica', 'Arial', 'sans-serif';
  font-weight: bold;
  /* font-family: 'Catamaran', 'Roboto', 'Helvetica', 'Arial', 'sans-serif'; */
}

#dcsupporttab {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  color: #434343;
  text-align: center;
  width: 150px;
  padding: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
  margin: auto;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#dcsupportcontainer {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  padding-top: 10px;
  color: #434343;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
  /*height: calc(100% - 43px); */
  display: none;
}

.dcbutton {
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 230px;
  height: 40px;
}

.dcthelabel {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #434343;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.nonsolid {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  border-color: #fff;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 3px;
}

#dcmessageus {
  text-transform: none;
}

#dcaslnow {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dccontainer">
  <p id="dcsupporttab">Support</p>
  <div id="dcsupportcontainer">
    <div class="dcbutton" id="dcaslnow">
      <a href="#" class="dcthelabel">ASL Now</a>
    </div>
    <div class="dcbutton" id="dctextchat">
      <a href="#" class="dcthelabel">Text Chat</a>
    </div>
    <div class="dcbutton nonsolid" id="dcmessageus">
      <a href="#" class="dcthelabel">Send Us a Message</a>
    </div>
    <p id="dcvpinfo">Video Chat: (123) 456-7890</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've tried various techniques.  I've tried toggling with CSS alone using CSS animation and `toggleClass`, I've tried using `slide`, and I've tried using `slideToggle`. I also tried using `display: block;` instead of using flexbox.  Both had the same effect.  Researching the internet yielded several possible solutions (which I've tried, but all came out with the same result), and those usually weren't based on an element being fixed at bottom of window.  The only one that came closest to what I was looking for was this:

http://atomicrobotdesign.com/blog_media/toggleslide_multiple.html

But strangely, when I attempted to use the same code that used, nothing happened. Clicking did not bring up the menu.  I'm at a loss at this point.  Where am I going wrong?

This is my latest attempt (using above code): https://codepen.io/doncullen/pen/JjdrxzY

Comment: I simply un-commented your css lines in the jquery in your codepen and it worked unless I am misunderstanding what you are trying to do. `if(supTabState) {
                $("#dccontainer").css('bottom', '0px');<---
                $(this).show("slide", { direction: "down" }, 1000);
            } else {
                $("#dccontainer").css('bottom', '-150px');<---
                $(this).show("slide", { direction: "up" }, 1000);
            }`

Comment: I assume this is what you are attempting to do, yes?
https://codepen.io/dlandry7/pen/YzXrbGX

Comment: As mentioned above, it does produce the desired behavior by sliding it up from past the bottom of the window and it displays correctly. But it means the menu is pushing the page past the bottom of the page rather than simply being hidden. So when it's "hidden", one can simply scroll down and see the full menu which shouldn't be the case.  Try scrolling down, you'll still see the menu when it's "hidden".

Comment: Okay I see, try adding `$("#dccontainer").css('position', 'fixed');` to the if statement. Try my codepen fork again. codepen.io/dlandry7/pen/YzXrbGX

Comment: I see some progress! It doesn't stay at bottom of page though, sliding distorts it still. And it seems to flicker from center to left then back to center while sliding.  Close though!!

Comment: Just wanted to add I appreciate your trying to help, @dalelandry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question *Where am I going wrong*: you're specifying a fixed height of 200px on `#dccontainer`. Specifying a fixed height to the container renders the jQuery's [`slideToggle`](https://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/) useless. jQuery's `slideToggle` animates the height of the given element, and in your case, you're animating `#dcsupportcontainer`. Even though you're animating the height of `#dcsupportcontainer` to 0px using `slideToggle`, the whole support *block* will still remain 200px in height. This causes makes the whole *block* not to *move down* when the `#dcsupportcontainer` is gone. You can, of course, manually calculate and assign the new `bottom` value to `#dccontainer`, but that's a real hassle and really unintuitive.

Not wanting to calculate the `bottom` value myself, I will not set a height to `#dccontainer` and just let its height be. It will set its height to all its children's requirements (the default value is `auto`). Furthermore, instead of using `fixed`, you used `absolute`. You should use `fixed` here as you want the support block to always be visible (even when the user scrolls down); this means that you should position it based on your viewport and not an element (read more about positioning [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Positioning)). I also did minor adjustments on your CSS styles so that it's a tad more concise. One last thing, I suggest that you revisit flexbox [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox) to utilise it better.

Here's a working solution:

```js
// First time accessing, hide the support buttons section
$('#dcsupportcontainer').hide()

$("#dcsupporttab").click(function() {
  $('#dcsupportcontainer').slideToggle(500)
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  min-width: 100vw;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

#dccontainer {
  position: fixed;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 0px;
  transform: translateX(-50%);

  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  width: 50vw;
  min-width: 200px;
  font-family: 'Roboto', 'Helvetica', 'Arial', 'sans-serif';
}

#dccontainer * {
  padding: 7px 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

#dcsupporttab {
  font-weight: bold;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  background: #121212;
  color: #ffffffee;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#dcsupportcontainer {
  border: 1px solid #121212;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dccontainer">
  <p id="dcsupporttab">Support</p>
  <div id="dcsupportcontainer">
    <div class="dcbutton" id="dcaslnow">
      <a href="#" class="dcthelabel">ASL Now</a>
    </div>
    <div class="dcbutton" id="dctextchat">
      <a href="#" class="dcthelabel">Text Chat</a>
    </div>
    <div class="dcbutton nonsolid" id="dcmessageus">
      <a href="#" class="dcthelabel">Send Us a Message</a>
    </div>
    <p id="dcvpinfo">Video Chat: (123) 456-7890</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your solution hits all of the needed factors! 

Interestingly, having height applied allows `justify-content: space-evenly;` to work; without it, there's no space in between at all.  Setting margin will not work as flexbox is being used.  While I want the height to be flexible (as the height will vary), spacing is needed between buttons.

Comment: Wanted to edit, but was past 5 minutes.  I was wrong, setting margin on the `dcbutton` class solved the minimum spacing issue.  Everything is working as expected, thank you for going into the effort of explaining where I went wrong, it was insightful!

Comment: @DonCullen Great to hear that the explanation helped ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Just take the fixed height from your main container #dccontainer, and everything will be fine. You should also remove a few lines of your javascript code to fix everything. That fixed height of dccontainer makes the whole nav to stand 200px up from the bottom of your page and that makes you use more jQuery to fix it at the bottom. Remember that the bottom: 0px will set the bottom of your element at the 0px bottom of its container.

```js
$("#dcsupporttab").click(function() {
  $('#dcsupportcontainer').slideToggle(500, function() {
    //execute this after slideToggle is done
  });
});
```

```css
#dccontainer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 300px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -150px;
  transition: .5s;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#dccontainer * {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  font-family: 'Roboto', 'Helvetica', 'Arial', 'sans-serif';
  font-weight: bold;
  /* font-family: 'Catamaran', 'Roboto', 'Helvetica', 'Arial', 'sans-serif'; */
}

#dcsupporttab {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  color: #434343;
  text-align: center;
  width: 150px;
  padding: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
  margin: auto;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#dcsupportcontainer {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  padding-top: 10px;
  color: #434343;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
  /*height: calc(100% - 43px); */
  display: none;
}

.dcbutton {
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 230px;
  height: 40px;
}

.dcthelabel {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #434343;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.nonsolid {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  border-color: #fff;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 3px;
}

#dcmessageus {
  text-transform: none;
}

#dcaslnow {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dccontainer">
  <p id="dcsupporttab">Support</p>
  <div id="dcsupportcontainer">
    <div class="dcbutton" id="dcaslnow">
      <a href="#" class="dcthelabel">ASL Now</a>
    </div>
    <div class="dcbutton" id="dctextchat">
      <a href="#" class="dcthelabel">Text Chat</a>
    </div>
    <div class="dcbutton nonsolid" id="dcmessageus">
      <a href="#" class="dcthelabel">Send Us a Message</a>
    </div>
    <p id="dcvpinfo">Video Chat: (123) 456-7890</p>
  </div>
</div>
```